# Google App Engine - Brightcove Integration

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, upload, brightcove

I try to integrate the upload of video with Brightcove in Java:

http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/java-example-upload-video

But with GAE we cannot write on disk so I got the following exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted
>   class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more
>   details.

The exception occurs at this line: (UploadVideo.java)

```
 // Parse the request into a list of DiskFileItems
 List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

Because it's trying to use `org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*` which will not work with GAE.

I'm looking for a way around this. Looks like it might be really tricky so i'm open to any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common approach is to use the BlobStore.  See:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview
The idea is:  Provide the blobstore-created upload URL via your webpage's form (i.e. the "uploading using an HTML form" section of the brightcove example).  The blobstore's createUploadUrl function takes an argument that is a callback URL... I.e. after the file is uploaded and stored into the BlobStore, GAE will request your callback URL.  In that request, you can send the video blob to Brightcove via JSON (or, perhaps better, spawn a Task to send it to Brightcove).

Google Cloud Storage is another option, see:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview
Instead of writing to a file, you would write to Cloud Storage request stream.

Comment: Yes i think BlobStore will not work because of the file size. I already looked at Google Cloud Storage and i think i'll go all the way with them then and not use BrightCove, thanks for your help!